# Using Spatial Join/Merge/Table View in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, in-memory

I have developed a model that spatially joins a series of line segments to line and point segments using the "One to One", "Closest" function and creating a "distanceTo" field in feet. The model then merges and creates a table view however my output seems to be duplicated multiple times.

The model for the spatial joins is using the `in_memory\layer` function with the merged layer being a parameter. I would like the output to be just one record per unique id (`Priority_ID`).

[image: Model Diagram]
[image: Model Results]

Comment: Where is the "distanceTo" field here? Are those the fields having "Distance" e.g. StreetDistance?